# extract zip file and delete by batch

Tags: batch, tar, unzip

I want to unzip all the .zip files in a download directory like `"D:\Download"`,
and then the zip files should be deleted after the contents have been extracted to a folder with the zip file name, e.g. `foo.zip` extracted to `foo\`

What I can think of to achieve this task is first to pick an unZip program, which could be 7zip or the Windows 10 built-in 'extract-all' from the context menu or the tar.exe supported from 1909.

Let's pick the `tar.exe` for *example*, my batch should be something like,

```
for %%G in (D:\Download\*.zip) do (
        tar.exe -xf %%G
        if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
            del %%G
          )
      )
```

But actually it just cannot do the job as expected. Any idea please?

Comment: `tar` is not able to unpack the `.zip` format. `.tar` or `.tgz` format is completely different from `.zip`. You should use 7Zip, `unzip`, PKZIP or something similar that understands the `.zip` format.